# Combine Stream together from HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream

I have a webservice that I need to consume files from. The problem is this webservice limits API calls to 100MB but the files are larger then 100MB. So they recommended we use the the Range header. I added the range to the HttpWebRequest. My problem seems to be combining the Streams. I think it stems from the fact that I cannot create a instance of the ConnectSream (which I think is what GetResponseStream returns). So I have to create a MemoryStream instead. Except when I do it this way I try to open a test zip file I uploaded it wont open. I compared the downloaded file with my original copy and the downloaded file has no actual data in it, in a hex view it shows all 0's. How can I fix this so I can combine the two streams and then save the file to the disk?

```
foreach (var largeFile in LargeFilesToDownload)
{
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();

    while (endSize <= largeFile.Value)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest downReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://webserviceurl/" + largeFile.Key);
            downReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + API_TOKEN);
            downReq.AddRange(startSize, endSize);
            downReq.Method = "GET";
            using (var eresp2 = (HttpWebResponse)downReq.GetResponse())
            {
                eresp2.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(stream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            //Handle Exception
        }
        //Set new startSize and endSize here
    }

    try
    {
        //check to make sure path exists here

        string path = SaveLocation + @"\" + rootDir + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(largeFile.Key);

        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
        FilesToDelete.Add(largeFile.Key);
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        //Handle Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set the start and end size? How do you know you're actually reading the full file size?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov startSize is initially set to 0, and then subsequently set to the end size of that iteration. endSize is incremented by 100MB each iteration until the last one where it just downloads the remaining data. The stream has the correct length if I add a break point, and the file size is the exact size in bytes it should be it just fails to open.

Comment: Are you sure the generated file is a zip?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Well windows recognizes it as a zip file, same with 7zip, but when you go to open it you get an error.

Comment: It recognizes it as a zip file only if you save it with a zip extension in your code.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov the filename and extension is passed in from the webservice, which is what is contained in the LargeFilesToDownload dictionary. It contains the name (since on webservice system that has to be unique) and the then the size in bytes of the file.